# How to use shaders more efficiently in c++/sfml?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, sfml

I'm working on a sort of ascii canvas for a game. I assumed it would be more efficient to to use a spritesheet of ascii glyphs in cp437 style to draw the ascii art. I needed a way to color the background and foreground of the glyphs so I'm using a fragment shader. Using the shader drops me to 7 fps. Not using the shader, I get about 131.

Am I doing something incorrectly? Is it just too expensive to loop through a vector of strings (and each character in the string), calculate the position of the glyph on the sheet, set the texture position, and then draw the sprite with a shader for each character?

```c++
int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow rt(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "Demo Game");
    
    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile("Resources/courier_8x16.png");
    texture.setSmooth(false);
    sf::Sprite sprite(texture);
    sf::Shader shader;
    shader.loadFromFile("cycle.frag", sf::Shader::Fragment);
    shader.setUniform("texture", sf::Shader::CurrentTexture);
    
    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;
    
    std::vector<std::string> chars = std::vector<std::string>(50, std::string(100, 'X'));
    while (rt.isOpen())
    {
        processEvents();
        timeSinceLastUpdate += clock.restart();

        while (timeSinceLastUpdate > TimePerFrame)
        {
            timeSinceLastUpdate -= TimePerFrame;
            processEvents();
            update(TimePerFrame);
        }
        
        //render();
        rt.clear();

        for (int y = 0; y < chars.size(); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < chars[y].size(); x++)
            {
                //bg and fg colors will be in a 2D vector and used here
                shader.setUniform("foreground", sf::Glsl::Vec4(std::Color.White));
                shader.setUniform("background", sf::Glsl::Vec4(std::Color.Black));
                
                //uses decimal value of char and dimensions
                //to find location of appropriate glyph in sprite sheet
                sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect((chars[y][x] % 16) * 8, (chars[y][x] / 16) * 16, 8, 16));
                sprite.setPosition(x * 8, y * 16);
                
                rt.draw(sprite, &shader);
            }

        }

        rt.display();
        
    }
}
```

Here's the shader code:

```
//////cycle.frag
uniform vec4 foreground;
uniform vec4 background;
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
    vec4 pixel = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
    if (pixel.r < .1)
        pixel = background;
    else
        pixel = foreground;
                
    gl_FragColor = pixel;
}
```

Here's the sprite sheet: (all the paragraph symbols are just placeholders)

[image: glyphs]

Comment: About to try out checking to see if the previous background and foreground color is the same as the one about to be drawn and if so, don't set the shader variables for that iteration.

Comment: Please clarify what "not using the shader" means. I can see many performance demanding operations in your code and have no idea which ones you deactivated and what is left.

Comment: Removing the two "shader.setUniform" calls from inside the second for loop and removing the second argument (&shader) from "rt.draw"

Comment: Is there any noticable improvement when placing the setUniform outside the loops?

Comment: Ideally they need to be in the loops because any position on the grid can have a different background color and be changed when the game updates. I was able to get a small performance increase from not calling setUniform if the previous colors are the same as the current ones. Someone else suggested using a vertex array instead of a bunch of sprites so I am looking into that.

Comment: The problem is the huge number of draw calls. You should gather all relevant data in the loop, then send these data to the GPU (with a vertex buffer or similar structure) and issue a single draw call.